# Flutter how to create Multi Card and select a color

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new in flutter, I want to create multi card with some option and select a option then change color. In my code when click one option number but all of color same change, please help to fix it.

link all code
[https://github.com/gunartha/Multi-Question-and-multi-selection-with-color-option]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are using same color for all the 15 questions.
To have each of the 15 card behave independently you need List of size 15. Check the changes made by me below. This should fix your problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Click Color Card',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final kSecondaryColor = Color(0xFF8B94BC);
  final kPrimaryColor = Color(0xFF748BF5);
  final kGreenColor = Color(0xFFAAF39C);
  final kRedColor = Color(0xFFF7BCBD);
  final kYellowColor = Color(0xFFF0EE8C);
  final kGrayColor = Color(0xFFD8D5D5);
  final kBlackColor = Color(0xFF101010);

  List<Color> colorYes = List.filled(15, Color(0xFFD8D5D5));
  List<Color> colorNo = List.filled(15, Color(0xFFD8D5D5));
  List<Color> colorNA = List.filled(15, Color(0xFFD8D5D5));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Click Multi color"),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 15,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return new Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                  height: 250,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                  ),
                  child: Card(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Text("Question $index"),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          //yes
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              colorYes[index] = kGreenColor;
                              colorNo[index] = kGrayColor;
                              colorNA[index] = kGrayColor;
                            });
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            width: 200,
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                              color: colorYes[index],
                            ),
                            child: Container(
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Yes",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              colorYes[index] = kGrayColor;
                              colorNo[index] = kRedColor;
                              colorNA[index] = kGrayColor;
                            });
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            width: 200,
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                              color: colorNo[index],
                            ),
                            child: Container(
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  "No",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              colorYes[index] = kGrayColor;
                              colorNo[index] = kGrayColor;
                              colorNA[index] = kYellowColor;
                            });
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            width: 200,
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                              color: colorNA[index],
                            ),
                            child: Container(
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  "N/A",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. this work for me

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put extra effort, Simply create question answer bean and store data in that. when you change state then you find same data in bean and you can render card color on specific card.

```
        class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Click Color Card',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(),
        );
      }
    }

    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      final kSecondaryColor = Color(0xFF8B94BC);
      final kPrimaryColor = Color(0xFF748BF5);
      final kGreenColor = Color(0xFFAAF39C);
      final kRedColor = Color(0xFFF7BCBD);
      final kYellowColor = Color(0xFFF0EE8C);
      final kGrayColor = Color(0xFFD8D5D5);
      final kBlackColor = Color(0xFF101010);

      Color colorYes = Color(0xFFD8D5D5);
      Color colorNo = Color(0xFFD8D5D5);
      Color colorNA = Color(0xFFD8D5D5);

      List<QueAnsBean> data = [];

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        generateBean();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Click Multi color"),
            ),
            body: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 15,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  QueAnsBean item = data[index];
                  return new Center(
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                      height: 250,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                      ),
                      child: Card(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                            ),
                            Text("${item._que}"),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            InkWell(
                              //yes
                              onTap: () {
                                item._answer = "1";
                                setState(() {});
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                width: 200,
                                height: 50,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                                  color: item._answer == "1"
                                      ? kGreenColor
                                      : kGrayColor,
                                ),
                                child: Container(
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Yes",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      ),
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                item._answer = "2";
                                setState(() {});
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                width: 200,
                                height: 50,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                                  color:
                                      item._answer == "2" ? kRedColor : kGrayColor,
                                ),
                                child: Container(
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "No",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      ),
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                item._answer = "3";
                                setState(() {});
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                width: 200,
                                height: 50,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                                  color: item._answer == "3"
                                      ? kYellowColor
                                      : kGrayColor,
                                ),
                                child: Container(
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "N/A",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      ),
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }));
      }

      void generateBean() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
          data.add(QueAnsBean(que: "Question - $i", answer: ""));
        }
      }
    }

    class QueAnsBean {
      String? _que;
      String? _answer;

      String? get que => _que;

      String? get answer => _answer;

      QueAnsBean({String? que, String? answer}) {
        _que = que;
        _answer = answer;
      }

      QueAnsBean.fromJson(dynamic json) {
        _que = json["que"];
        _answer = json["Answer"];
      }

      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        var map = <String, dynamic>{};
        map["que"] = _que;
        map["Answer"] = _answer;
        return map;
      }
    }
```